# Creating PivotChart with Apache POI Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am trying to create pivotchart from a pivot table. How can it be done by using Apache POI? I searched Google but could not find any useful informaion. All information is about creating Pivot tables.

Comment: This is literally the first hit on google for "apache poi pivot table": https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreatePivotTable.java

Comment: @rabbitguy It is about pivot table not pivot chart

Comment: Charts are largely not supported in Apache POI. This shouldn't be the avenue you are looking at to modify or create charts since it isn't supported. Basically, you can write out the data from charts, but don't expect much else